# Is there a way to adjust drag'n'drop release pressure on Force Touchpad?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I recently switched from 2013 MBP with physical touchpad to new M1 Macbook and it has very annoying drag'n'drop behaviour.

If you click without moving your finger it behaves as expected - once you release finger pressure below certain value (adjustable in System Preferences) it de-clicks, but if you move finger after pressing touchpad (when you drag'n'drop or select text) you need to lift finger a lot of more, almost have to let it off from surface. It creates very bad experience, very often it does not release when I feel it should (because I'm below threshold for normal click) and object I was dragging lands in a different spot then I expected. It makes using apps based around drag'n'drop like Logic Pro borderline unusable on touchpad.

I know that I can enable 3 finger drag in Accessibility and I also know that you can click with one finger and move cursor with second one. I'm looking for more permanent solution, I'm fine with fiddling in Terminal or installing shady 3rd party apps.